# Ideal of ideal is ideal of Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, ideals

Q: Let L be a Lie algebra, J be its ideal and I is an ideal of J, then I is an ideal of L.

My attempt:
We know that for any ideal J of Lie algebra L: [L, J] and [J, L] are in J.
So i in I, j in J and l in L:
[i, [j, l]] =-[j, [l, i]] - [l, [i, j]]
The RHS is in I, thus LHS as well.
My question is can we deduce that [l, i] is in  I (so Q is proven)?

Comment: [In this older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/629723/11619) it is also stated that the result is false in general, but true in a special case.

Comment: You could (possibly should?) have left the question in its earlier form. The way it is currently written leaves it in a form that is [not quite up to the standards outlined in our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Nobody here will think less of you for your original thinking leading to a dead end. On the other hand, if the question looks like an attempt to outsource an assignment, that may attract negative attention. It may not feel natural to a new user, but that's the way site policies have developed to work. Don't worry!

Comment: I agree, please leave the question as it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim is false as stated.

Consider the strictly upper triangular $3\times 3$ matrices. They are spanned by the elementary matrices $e_{12}$, $e_{13}$ and $e_{23}$, where the subscripts indicate the position of the $1$ (the rest of the entries are all zeros). They have the commutator relations
$$[e_{12},e_{13}]=0,\quad [e_{12},e_{23}]=e_{13},\quad [e_{23},e_{13}]=0.$$

Let $L=\langle e_{12},e_{13},e_{23}\rangle$, $J=\langle e_{12},e_{13}\rangle$,
$I=\langle e_{12}+e_{13}\rangle$. Then $[L,L]\subset J$, so $J$ is an ideal. The ideal $J$ is an abelian Lie algebra, so $I\subset J$ is an ideal. But $I$ is not an ideal of $L$ as
$$[e_{12}+e_{13},e_{23}]=e_{13}\notin I.$$

Comment: It is easier to construct examples, when you have a similar sequence of groups at hand. I just recalled a fitting example I cooked up for my group theory course last Spring. $G_3\unlhd G_2\unlhd G_1$ such that $G_3$ is not a normal subgroup of $G_1$. These are the matching Lie algebras.

Comment: I am surprised if this has not been covered already. I could not find it. Alas, I no longer frequent the Lie algebra tag, so I'm rusty with useful buzzwords for the search engine :-(

Comment: Jyrki, I just found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3003181/ideals-of-a-characteristic-ideal) saying that it only works if the ideal is characteristic. But this has no concrete counterexample (except for a comment by Yves). So I have upvoted your post.

Comment: Thanks @Dietrich. I feel a bit better about this if you could not find a matching old thread either.